# Heroku Node Stormpath

Tags: node.js, heroku, stormpath

**UPDATE**

I uploaded this to Azure and it worked immediately - I believe the issue had something to do with the .env file but I cannot be sure.

So I followed the guide [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/build-app-nodejs-express-passport-stormpath/):

and am trying to push the app to Heroku. I have all my config vars correct - however, when the application launches on heroku I receive:

```
/app/node_modules/stormpath/lib/ds/RequestExecutor.js:59
 npm ERR! VisualVMail@0.0.1 start: `node ./bin/www`
 npm ERR! Exit status 8
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Failed at the VisualVMail@0.0.1 start script.
 npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the VisualVMail package,
 npm ERR! not with npm itself.
 npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
 npm ERR! You can get their info via:
 npm ERR!     npm owner ls VisualVMail
 npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
 npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
 npm ERR! command "/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "st

 npm ERR! cwd /app
 npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
 npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
 npm ERR! not ok code 0

     throw new Error('request.uri field is required.');
```

Has anyone been able to get Stormpath / nodejs / heroku running, particularly with this sample application?

Comment: I'm having exact same issue. Did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an issue with the VisualVMail package -- can you try debugging that? It says in the error that request.uri is required.

Comment: lol yes thats the name of the app. The problem is this app executes fine locally, on azure and on an ec2 vm I spun up - however it does not execute within heroku. .<= which is odd b/c heroku runs on ec2

Comment: Can you paste a link to your code, or the snippet where visualmal is setup? It looks like the URI is missing somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The error "request.uri field is required" is from the stormpath library.  It would be helpful to see the stacktrace, can you look for it in /app/npm-debug.log?  It may be in your heroku logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

If, more recently you used the Stormpath automatic add-on - This is an issue with the way Heroku have setup their integrations with Stormpath (or vice-versa). I've sent them a bug report.

In your Heroku `Settings > Config Variables`; if you have a variable named `STORMPATH_URL`, remove it and add a new variable called `STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF` with its value as your application's href, e.g. `https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/<appIDhere>`.

Then it should work.

---

Or in the case of your env file, `STORMPATH_APP_HREF` should be `STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF`.